# Why does my multi-threaded app sometimes hang when it closes?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, critical-section

I'm using several critical sections in my application. The critical sections prevent large data blobs from being modified and accessed simultaneously by different threads.

AFAIK it's all working correctly except sometimes the application hangs when exiting. I'm wondering if this is related to my use of critical sections.

Is there a correct way to free TCriticalSection objects in a destructor?

*Thanks for all the answers. I'm looking over my code again with this new information in mind. Cheers!*

Comment: Check the call stack of the thread that's hanging to determine what's actually causing the hang. Don't just guess.

Comment: Thanks wj32, I didn't know I could check the call stack. Much better the guessing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Rob says, the only requirement is that you ensure that the critical section is not currently owned by any thread.  Not even the thread about to destroy it.  So there is no pattern to follow for correctly destroying a TCriticalSection, as such.  Only a required behaviour that your application must take steps to ensure occurs.

If your application is locking then I doubt it is the free'ing of any critical section that is responsible.  As MSDN says (in the link that Rob posted), the DeleteCriticalSection() (which is ultimately what free'ing a TCriticalSection calls) does not block any threads.

If you were free'ing a critical section that other threads were still trying to access you would get access violations and other unexpected behaviours, not deadlocks, as this little code sample should help you demonstrate:

```
implementation

uses
  syncobjs;


  type
    tworker = class(tthread)
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    end;


  var
    cs: TCriticalSection;
    worker: Tworker;


procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cs := TCriticalSection.Create;

  worker := tworker.Create(true);
  worker.FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;
  worker.Start;

  sleep(5000);

  cs.Enter;

  showmessage('will AV before you see this');
end;

{ tworker }

procedure tworker.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  cs.Free;
end;
```

Add to the implementation unit of a form, correcting the "TForm2" reference for the FormCreate() event handler as required.

In FormCreate() this creates a critical section then launches a thread whose sole purpose is to free that section.  We introduce a Sleep() delay to give the thread time to initialise and execute, then we try to enter the critical section ourselves.

We can't of course because it has been free'd.  But our code doesn't hang - it is not deadlocked trying to access a resource that is owned by something else, it simply blows up because, well, we're trying to access a resource that no longer exists.

You could be even more sure of creating an AV in this scenario by NIL'ing the critical section reference when it is free'd.

Now, try changing the FormCreate() code to this:

```
  cs := TCriticalSection.Create;

  worker := tworker.Create(true);
  worker.FreeOnTerminate := TRUE;

  cs.Enter;
  worker.Start;

  sleep(5000);

  cs.Leave;

  showmessage('appearances can be deceptive');
```

This changes things... now the main thread will take ownership of the critical section - the worker thread will now free the critical section while it is still owned by the main thread.

In this case however, the call to cs.Leave does not necessarily cause an access violation.  All that occurs in this scenario (afaict) is that the owning thread is allowed to "leave" the section as it would expect to (it doesn't of course, because the section has gone, but it *seems* to the thread that it has left the section it previously entered) ...

... in more complex scenarios an access violation or other error is possibly likely, as the memory previously used for the critical section object may be re-allocated to some other object by the time you call it's Leave() method, resulting in some call to some other unknown object or access to invalid memory etc.

Again, changing the worker.Execute() so that it NIL's the critical section ref after free'ing it would ensure an access violation on the attempt to call cs.Leave(), since Leave() calls Release() and Release() is virtual - calling a virtual method with a NIL reference is guaranteed to AV (ditto for Enter() which calls the virtual Acquire() method).

In any event:

Worst case: an exception or weird behaviour

"Best" case: the owning thread appears to believe it has "left" the section as normal.

In neither case is a deadlock or a hang going to occur simply as the result of when a critical section is free'd in one thread in relation to when other threads then try to enter or leave that critical section.

All of which is a round-a-bout way of saying that it sounds like you have a more fundamental race condition in your threading code not directly related to the free'ing of your critical sections.

In any event, I hope my little bit of investigative work might set you down the right path.

Comment: -1 because using the TCriticalSection instance as a global var was made global, which is a very bad design, even more for some sample code to show the right way of coding.

Comment: @A.Bouchez in fact declaring critical sections as global variables is frequently an excellent design choice

Comment: @David: No, it almost never is, because a CS should have close relation to the data it protects, which will probably not be global either. Locking should also be as fine-grained as possible, and strict control over the locking hierarchy is necessary to prevent deadlocks. All of this seems to point to CS being (in general) more local.

Comment: @mghie @A.Bouchez I offer the example of a system wide logging framework, or perhaps the lazy initialization using double checked locking on a global singleton. Some things really are best global! Whatever, -1 on the basis of this is stupid because the code is there to illustrate a different point, and to avoid a global variable would just obfuscate the point being made. Come on guys, look at the bigger picture here!

Comment: @David: I agree that the downvote was uncalled for, however I stand by my point. I don't buy your argument that "declaring critical sections as global variables is frequently an excellent design choice" - it may be necessary in rare cases (a global logging framework for example isn't one of those), but it's a necessary evil then, not a good choice.

Comment: @mghie How do you implement a global logging framework without global variables? And please don't pretend that class variables are not global variables!

Comment: @David: Well, *my* global logging framework consists of a singleton where log targets can be registered and unregistered. The object is created and destroyed in the `initialization` and `finalization` sections, respectively. It contains a CS member to protect the list of log targets, but there is no global CS to be found...

Comment: @mghie There is a global lock, it's contained inside your global singleton, you said so yourself.

Comment: @David: Wouldn't you agree that there is a noticeable difference between "declaring critical sections as global variables" and having a critical section as a (private) member of the class whose data it is protecting? There may or may not be instances of that class that are global variables, but that's completely beside the point.

Comment: @mghie Once the thing that is being protected gets more than trivially complex then grouping all related parts into an object is sensible. I think private/public issues are usually more important for sync objects whose use has to be carefully managed. I personally don't get hung up on global/local. Look at Application and Screen in the VCL. They are global, but that's as they should be because they are singletons.

Comment: @ A Bouchez - the code was to demonstrate a mechanism, not show a good design choice for critical sections as global variables.

Comment: @ All - there is no such thing as a "global variable" in Delphi.  The highest visibility that is possible is unit-interface.  This is close enough to what other languages call "global" that it is often confused as such.  The lengths that people go to to obfuscate the fact that sometimes data has to have such high visibility, allowing themselves to sleep at night pretending that they aren't using a "global" variable is ridiculous...  pity the poor people who have to maintain the code and de-obfuscate the spaghetti of singleton management code only to realise that "Aaaahhhh, it's a global!"

Comment: @All - supplemental... notice that the "singleton pattern" is synonymous with a GLOBAL object (by definition - one and only one and all references are to the same one).  The singleton "pattern" as often quoted doesn't actually dictate that you have to have a class with complicated lifetime management code - such things are necessary only in languages which specifically do not provide variables in the first place.  This complication of the pattern born of necessity in such languages has become confused with the "correct" way of implementing the pattern, imho.

Comment: GLOBAL variables are EVIL! What about if you want to have the same process run in parallel? Making the critical section local is a good practice. Just for testing purposes, it could make sense to have a 100% parallel-aware version of your data, then run them in concurrent access, as a stress test. In all my previous projects, when I used some GLOBAL variable, it sounded out later that it was a bad design choice. Some languages even don't allow this. About singleton, it's also a workaround (access C console from C++) made a feature. Bad feature IMHO.

Comment: @A.B I take it that you have a policy of never using the great many singletons in the VCL. No, I didn't think so. Look at your own code even. What's the interface public variable in SynGdiPlus?

Comment: @A B - Prohibiting globals is the bad design choice (for a language) because it imposes limits on application designers: witness the syntactic verbosity that this design choice then imposes on such languages, to declare simple things like symbolic constants, requiring an arbitrary "container" class.  Globals are neither good nor bad, per se.  Only specific uses of them can be labelled as such.  Dogmatically dismissing all uses of them as bad is simply lazy, side-stepping the business of engaging ones brain in order to make a proper assessment....

Comment: @A.B cont. ... The result often being code that adheres to the dogmatic idea of being "good design" but which in fact is anything but.  But the author can reject out of hand any such criticism because they didn't "use any bad design choices".  I have worked with such people - they never use with, they never use globals, the never do all sorts of things.  Including writing decent, understandable, maintainable code.

Comment: @David Indeed - I confess I use a global but it was driven by the design of the external GDI plus library. For a pure Delphi architecture, you will have to avoid globals.

Comment: @Deltics I agree with you of course. It depends on the purpose... David noticed that I use some globals in some of my units. So, as in real life, I'll write "NEVER DO THAT", but I'll do it anyway. But less often than if I told myself it was something I could do. As San Paul wrote: "For that which I do I allow not: for what I would, that do I not; but what I hate, that do I." Romans 7:15

Comment: @Deltics @A.Bouchez Yeah, I hate dogma too! There are loads of situations where globals are terrible, and situtations where they are the right choice. You just need to use the right solution for whatever the problem at hand is. Java and C# constants are a syntactical mess.

Comment: @A.Bouchez @Deltics you also appear to have a pathological aversion to checking GDI+ API calls for error conditions. Now that is very bad practice. You should stop worrying about the things that don't matter (i.e. dogmatic opinions on use of globals) and concentrate on the things that do matter (i.e. checking error codes!)

Comment: @David H - Wah?  Where did my approach to GDI+ and error codes come in to this?  And how is it even relevant ?!

Comment: @deltics argh that comment was not aimed directly at you, was meant to be a CC to you!

Comment: @David H : let me quote it again "For that which I do I allow not: for what I would, that do I not; but what I hate, that do I." Romans 7:15 In this particular case, globals were not needed at all. About errors checks in SynGdiPlus, you are perfectly right: we only handled main errors (like missing file or object creation failure). But it's not the place to talk about that. Most GDI+ wrapper just update a global status property, without raising exceptions for the first kind of error, and most user code won't check it. It's not a perfect solution either. You're welcome in our dedicated forum.

Answer (score 2):

Just make sure nothing still owns the critical section. Otherwise, [MSDN explains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682552.aspx), "the state of the threads waiting for ownership of the deleted critical section is undefined." Other than that, call `Free` on it like you do with all other objects.

Answer (score 1):

> AFAIK it's all working correctly except sometimes the application hangs when exiting. I'm wondering if this is related to my use of critical sections.

Yes it is. But the problem is likely not in the destruction. You probably have a deadlock.

Deadlocks are when two threads wait on two exclusive resources, each wanting both of them and each owning only one:

```
//Thread1:
FooLock.Enter;
BarLock.Enter;

//Thread2:
BarLock.Enter;
FooLock.Enter;
```

The way to fight these is to order your locks. If some thread wants two of them, it has to enter them only in specific order:

```
//Thread1:
FooLock.Enter;
BarLock.Enter;

//Thread2:
FooLock.Enter;
BarLock.Enter;
```

This way deadlock will not occur.

Many things can trigger deadlock, not only TWO critical sections. For instance, you might have used SendMessage (synchronous message dispatch) or Delphi's Synchronize AND one critical section:

```
//Thread1:
OnPaint:
  FooLock.Enter;
  FooLock.Leave;

//Thread2:
FooLock.Enter;
Synchronize(SomeProc);
FooLock.Leave;
```

Synchronize and SendMessage send messages to Thread1. To dispatch those messages, Thread1 needs to finish whatever work it's doing. For instance, OnPaint handler.

But to finish painting, it needs FooLock, which is taken by Thread2 which waits for Thread1 to finish painting. Deadlock.

The way to solve this is either to never use Synchronize and SendMessage (the best way), or at least to use them outside of any locks.

> Is there a correct way to free TCriticalSection objects in a destructor?

It does not matter where you are freeing TCriticalSection, in a destructor or not.

But before freeing TCriticalSection, you must ensure that all the threads that could have used it, are stopped or are in a state where they cannot possibly try to enter this section anymore.

For example, if your thread enters this section while dispatching a network message, you have to ensure network is disconnected and all the pending messages are processed.

Failing to do that will in most cases trigger access violations, sometimes nothing (if you're lucky), and rarely deadlocks.

Answer (score 1):

There are no magical in using TCriticalSection as well as in critical sections themselves. Try to replace TCriticalSection objects with plain API calls:

```
uses
  Windows, ...

var
  CS: TRTLCriticalSection;

...

EnterCriticalSection(CS);
....
here goes your code that you have to protect from access by multiple threads simultaneously
...
LeaveCriticalSection(FCS);
...

initialization
  InitializeCriticalSection(CS);

finalization
  DeleteCriticalSection(CS);
```

Switching to API will not harm clarity of your code, but, perhaps, help to reveal hidden bugs.

Comment: it's hard to see how this could help. The code will be just as clear either way. However you do it the enter/leave pair must be protected by a Try Finally block.

Comment: I echo that David, plus eliminating the TCriticalSection removes one additional debugging tool - the ability to NIL the reference to highlight uses of the reference after it has been free'd.

Answer (score 0):

You NEED to protect all critical sections using a try..finally block.

Use TRTLCriticalSection instead of a TCriticalSection class. It's cross-platform, and TCriticalSection is only an unnecessary wrapper around it.

If any exception occurs during the data process, then the critial section is not left, and another thread may block.

If you want fast response, you can also use TryEnterCriticalSection for some User Interface process or such.

Here are some good practice rules:

1. make your TRTLCriticalSection a property of a Class;
2. call InitializeCriticalSection in the class constructor, then DeleteCriticalSection in the class destructor;
3. use EnterCriticalSection()... try... do something... finally LeaveCriticalSection(); end;

Here is some code sample:

```
type
  TDataClass = class
  protected
    fLock: TRTLCriticalSection;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure SomeDataProcess;
  end;

constructor TDataClass.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  InitializeCriticalSection(fLock);
end;

destructor TDataClass.Destroy;
begin
  DeleteCriticalSection(fLock);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDataClass.SomeDataProcess;
begin
  EnterCriticalSection(fLock);
  try
    // some data process
  finally
    LeaveCriticalSection(fLock);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 use Try/Finally, this is essential, -1 replace TCriticalSection with TRTLCriticalSection, this is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: Is acceptable for one thread to acquire a lock and a second thread to release it?

Comment: @Shannon Check the official documentation of LeaveCriticalSection: "If a thread calls LeaveCriticalSection when it does not have ownership of the specified critical section object, an error occurs that may cause another thread using EnterCriticalSection to wait indefinitely. " So it's definitively NOT acceptable.

Comment: @David What about declaring it in the class handling the data?

Comment: @A.B that's good practice often but the difficulty with such simple examples as this is that it's hard to see where the need for locking arises.

Comment: @Shannon: If you ask the question whether it is "acceptable for one thread to acquire a lock and a second thread to release it?" then you should **really** take the time to learn some more on threading fundamentals. If you want some object for signalling purposes look into events and semaphores, a critical section is used for completely different things. If you do instead release a CS from a different thread than the one it was acquired in that may indeed be the cause of your hangs.

Comment: Ok, all critical sections are now protected by Try/Finally statements. Mghie's suggestion in another comment helped with re-organising my code.

Comment: @Shannon: congratulations! Welcome to the multi-threaded world. There is always room to improve design. It's a really good point that you ask for advice, make yourself your idea from experiment, then correct your code! :)

Comment: @A.Bouchez: Thanks! I've still got a lot to learn but I enjoy the process. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the only explicit synchronisation code in your app is through critical sections then it shouldn't be too difficult to track this down.

You indicate that you have only seen the deadlock on termination. Of course this doesn't mean that it cannot happen during normal operation of your app, but my guess (and we have to guess without more information) is that it is an important clue.

I would hypothesise that the error may be related to the way in which threads are forcibly terminated. A deadlock such as you describe would happen if a thread terminated whilst still holding the lock, but then another thread attempted to acquire the lock before it had a chance to terminate.

A very simple thing to do which may fix the problem immediately is to ensure, as others have correctly said, that all uses of the lock are protected by Try/Finally.  This really is a critical point to make.

There are two main patterns for resource lifetime management in Delphi, as follows:

```
lock.Acquire;
Try
  DoSomething();
Finally
  lock.Release;
End;
```

The other main pattern is pairing acquisition/release in Create/Destroy, but that is far less common in the case of locks.

Assuming that your usage pattern for the locks is as I suspect (i.e. acquireand release inside the same method), can you confirm that all uses are protected by Try/Finally?

Comment: I don't see how I can use Try/Finally blocks in my situation. I'm using a thread to load large files to avoid blocking other parts of the application. The lock says "This file is being loaded now, do not interrupt or use the data."

Comment: @shannon I don't see how you draw that conclusion. How can you be sure that your acquire will pair with a release if you don't use Try/Finally?

Comment: @Shannon: See my other comment. A lock says no such thing, if you want that look into events and semaphores, or use the lock only to protect the variable that says "file is being loaded".

Comment: @David. Good point. I was working under the assumption that my code would always run without exceptions.

Comment: @mghie. Using the lock to protect a variable makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your application only hangs/ deadlocks on exit please check the onterminate event for all threads. If the main thread signals for the other threads to terminate and then waits for them before freeing them. It is important not to make any synchronised calls in the on terminate event. This can cause a dead lock as the main thread waits for the worker thread to terminate. But the synchronise call is waiting on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Don't delete critical sections at object's destructor. Sometimes will cause your application to crash.

Use a seperate method which deletes the critical section.

procedure someobject.deleteCritical();
begin
  DeleteCriticalSection(criticalSection);
end;

destructor someobject.destroy();
begin
  // Do your release tasks here
end;

1) You call delete critical section
2) After you release(free) the object

Comment: Could you please provide a code example? It would make your answer easier to understand.